# CSS grayscale with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, grayscale

i have some css for changing my image into grayscale (with some svg for firefox)

```
img.grayscale{
            filter: grayscale(100%);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
            -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); 
            -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
            filter: gray;
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
        }
```

but now i want animation on hover for changing the value of the grayscale to 0.

I have this code but it doesn't do anything (on chrome of course), i have no idea why it doesn't animate at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".grayscale").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale('0'%)'
                }, 300);
            }
        );
    </script>
```

I think it's possible to animate the % from 100% to 0%, isn't it?

Edit : i'm trying to do for all browsers, not only chrome but i do my tests on chrome that's why i'm not changing all the properties. I think when i'll found the answer for chrome i'll can do the same for the other browers :)

Comment: try removing the extra quotes in `'grayscale('0'%)'`

Answer (score 12):

Why use animate() at all? You're already only animating for webkit, so why not use the transition property and classes to trigger the animation? Like this:

```
img {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
}

img.grayscale {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

And then just remove the class by calling

> $('img.grayscale').removeClass('grayscale');

Note: I don't know what the specific property is to just animate just the grayscale, but if you're not doing any other transitions on the element, transitioning "all" works just fine.

Comment: well i'm trying to animate for every browser, but i'm testing the animate() function on chrome because i use chrome for my tests.

I thought if i can target one property it will be easy to target another property :)

Comment: as of today, FF 35 implemented the filters, and now this is the proper answer and should be accepted

Answer (score 1):

You may use my silly function. But it works :)

HTML;

```
<img src ="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/American_McGee_Alice_box.gif" border="0" class="ongray" />
```

CSS;

```
img {-webkit-transition:-webkit-filter 0.3s ease-in-out;}
.g {-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);}
```

JS;

```
$(".ongray").hover(
    function(){$(this).addClass("g")},
    function(){$(this).removeClass("g");}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEC92/3/

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".grayscale").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).animate($(this).css("-webkit-filter" , "grayscale('0'%)"), 300);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
      $(".grayscale").hover(
          function () {
              $(this).animate($(this).css("-webkit-filter" , "grayscale(0%)"), 1000);
          }
      );
  </script>`
With this the change is made but not the animation :(

Comment: $(this).css( "-webkit-transition" , "1000ms" );
$(this).css("-webkit-filter" , "grayscale(100%)");
This will make the animation too :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set inline css using **onmouseover** and **onmouseout**

```
<img src="image.jpg" onmouseover="$(this).css('-webkit-filter','grayscale(100%)')" onmouseout="$(this).css('-webkit-filter','grayscale(0%)')" style="-webkit-transition:1000ms;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.grayscale{
        filter: grayscale(0%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);   }

.grayscale:hover{
            filter: grayscale(100%);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);   }
```